# Is there any way to crawl my native android app

Tags: android, web-crawler

I have my native android app in play store, in recent days my app gets multiple request frequently  from a particular user, for time being in have blocked that particular device id, i fear would be there any chance to crawl my app? 
Is there any way of crawling android app content?

Comment: Is it possible to crawl contents and pages of Android App like we can crawl contents easily of any webpage by just getting source code of that URL. Is it possible to get some unique id (like URL) for a page of Android App and how to then get its source code?

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is! You can open your APK like any zip archive and open whatever you want. You can use aapt tool from Android SDK to replace some parts. And you can decompile your code using undex tools. It will not be exactly what you used, but they will be able to modify your application.

You can do it harder for them, if you use some obfuscation tools like Proguard. You cannot prevent completely revealing your code however. It is much harder to disassemble native code, but still possible. Make sure you do not compile symbols for all functions into release library. See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aix-symbol-visibility/ for examples.

If you have something really valuable, only secure way it to process data on your secured server without giving your code to the user. All code you give on the user's device can be decompiled. It differs only by how hard it is and how much he has to spend to do that.

I may not have understood what you meant by crawl your app though.

Comment: Its not exactly. Crawling in sense is any automatic tool that can fetch my data which I am showing in my android screen.

Comment: Well it is really easy to get any resources you bundle into the application. Depends on where do that data come from. Do you secure traffic to your servers? Device owner can install own certificate and do MITM attack on SSL connections. You can avoid it by trusting only to certificates built into the application. If it is offline, depends on how much he can guess what you do with that data and whether he can understand your algorithm. Do you encrypt data bundled and decrypt runtime?

Comment: Is it possible to crawl contents and pages of Android App like we can crawl  contents easily of any webpage by just getting source code of that URL. Is it possible to get some unique id (like URL) for a page of Android App and how to then get its source code?

Comment: @Ankit: there is no any direct way to crawl the mobile app content as possible in webpages.